# MySQL InnoDB deadlock

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I try to understand why deadlock must happend when execute statements below.

For example:

Transaction 1: `select 'row 1' (s lock);`

Transaction 2: `update 'row 1'(x lock);`

Transaction 1: `update 'row 1'(x lock);`

than transaction 2 will deadlock.

The offical deadlock example:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlock-example.html

I think update operation from transaction 1 is unnecessary to wait x lock from transaction 2.

Because:

- The x lock from transaction 2 never actually update the row1.
- Transaction 1 already has the only s lock on row 1.

Answer (score 0):

The "isolation mode" may matter.

To avoid the deadlock, you should *probably* do `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`.  Without that, the processing is preventing you from having an update that might be based on stale info.